# Why isn't LOG10 calculated in SSAS?

Tags: math, ssas

In t-sql, `select log10(3000/3)` returns 3.

In SSAS, if I include it as part of a *Calculation*, it returns `null`.

What's the correct way to return the *log10* in SSAS?

[image]

Comment: Whoever voted to close it, speak up. Don't be shy.

Answer (score 0):

By prefixing the *log* function with `VBA`, and then dividing it by LOG(10) to convert to log base ten.

```
VBA![Log](x)/VBA![Log](10)
```